# Do not encrpyt spaces

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption

for my Coursework i need to encrypt a string however i need to make sure that the spaces in the string are not encrypted e.g.

```
if message == " " or 32:
      then do not encrypt
else:
     encrypt the character
```

I know this code won't work (it was an idea for how I could lay it out) so how would I make sure the spaces are not encrypted in the string?

Comment: `If not message.isspace()`.In your code  `or 32` always evaluate to True as 32 is a non falsey value. It would be `if message == " " or  ord(message) 32: ` but both are doing the same thing so it is redundant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would split the message using built in .split(' ') method. This seperates the message into a list (assuming your message is a string!) at each space. Loop through the list encoding each value before finally joining the list back into a string!

```
data = "Hello world, my name dosen't matter!"

data = data.split(' ')
for i in data:
    i.encode()
data = ' '.join(data)
print data
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you loop through the message, and encrypt whenever it is not a space.

```
encrypted_message=''
for character in message:
  if character != ' ':
    encrypted_message += encrypt(character)
  else:
    encrypted_message += character
print encrypted_messsage
```

print or return as the case might be. Include it in a def for a function

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can take your whole string and remove every space, like :

```
message.replace(' ', '')
```

Or you can build a `for` loop slightly as you started (as strings are sequences in python):

```
for char in message:
    if ' ' in char:
        continue # And do nothing
    else:
        # Do the encryption job with the character
```

(There is other way to make the condition simplier, like `if ' ' not in char:` without `else` for example)

Comment: I think the whole idea is to preserve them

Comment: Yes you're probably right, I edited my post! (It isn't really specified thus!)

Answer (score 0):

You can substitute the spaces with other characters like #, | and so on and encrypt the whole string then. This way the requirements "Spaces are not encrypted" is fulfilled.

You could also split the string where spaces are and encrypt every word separately. Then you can concatenate the list and have an encrypted string again. This way the requirements "Spaces are not encrypted" is fulfilled.

But I am not sure, whether this is what you want. Maybe you have additional requirements not stated yet.